# User confirmation is not enabled on this site : Moodle Web Service

Tags: authentication, moodle

When i try to check if user is valid or not (using username and password) using the web service function
'core_auth_confirm_user' then it says 'User confirmation is not enabled on this site' with errorcode
'confirmationnotenabled'. If anyone knows to fix this, then please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Logged in your Moodle as an admin, go to `admin/search.php` and search for the setting `registerauth`. Get sure the setting has a value set other than `Disable`. For example, you can set it as `Email-based self-registration`, in this case the auth plugin that will handle the confirmation would be `auth_email`. It is also possible that this error may arise if you have somehow selected other auth plugin and that plugin does not implement the `can_confirm()` as returning `true` in its `auth.php` config file, but this is very unlikely IMO.